# integration tests failing with 401 error for secure endpoints. Mockmvc not able to authenticate

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, mockmvc

I'm writing integration tests for secured endpoints and they are all failing with 401 response. I am using JWT. for some reason mockmvc is not able to authenticate someone could help on what the issue is. here is the code

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class RestEndpointsIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(wac)
                .apply(springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain))
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    void getAllTransactionsSuccessTest() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/transactions/account?account_id=1")
            //.with(user(AuthenticatedUser.builder().role("API_ADMIN").username("admin_user").build())))
             .with(authentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                "admin_user",
                null,
                Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("API_ADMIN"))
            ))))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.totalElements").value(50))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.transactions").exists());

    }

}
```

I have tried using @MockUser as well and still getting the 401 response

secuirty config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebSecurityConfig
extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        ((HttpSecurity)((HttpSecurity)((ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl)((ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl)((HttpSecurity)httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()).authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/transactions/all").hasRole("API_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(new String[]{"/auth/token","/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui","/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html","/api/swagger-ui.html",
                    "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/**","/favicon.ico","/**/*.png","/**/*.gif","/**/*.svg","/**/*.jpg","/**/*.html","/**/*.css","/**/*.js"})).permitAll()
                .anyRequest()).authenticated().and()).exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((AuthenticationEntryPoint)this.unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()).sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.cors();
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore((Filter)this.authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(new AuthenticationProvider[]{this.authenticationProvider}));
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager());
        authenticationTokenFilter
                .setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((AuthenticationSuccessHandler)new JwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
        return authenticationTokenFilter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you use `@Autowired` for getting autoconfiguring `MockMvc` instance, but in a *same time* you configure it self in `setUp()`

You must remove self configuration for mockMvc and must use `@WithMockUser` for using default test user configuration for tests (you can see defaults in `WithMockUser.class`)

```java
@WithMockUser
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class RestEndpointsIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Test
    void getAllTransactionsSuccessTest() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/transactions/account?account_id=1"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.totalElements").value(50))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.transactions").exists());

    }

}
```

if you need use different user attributes for testing you can specify `@WithMockUser` self attributes (like username, password etc.)

Required dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What is you AbstractIntegrationTest does in background?

Comment: its just for starting up mysql database testcontainer nothing to do with web

Comment: @Gannebal Barka still getting the 401 even with the above refactors

Comment: maybe you have some other beans which configure your environment?
I mean when you adding `SpringSecurity` usually you adding security configurar like `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` or another?

Comment: yea I have a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter I have added it check it out

Comment: i see you add cors and in request you must use it(cors headers) and you must configure cors for you endpoint, 


*Anyway* lets try to disable this configuration class (just for test, we need understand that's this class affected you)

Comment: I have disabled it and now it works so it must be a config in there. disabling cors doesnt work though

Comment: i think it depends of type of enabled for authorization. If you need make a tests for checking authoriztion process - you must lerm more how you can configure different authorization type for `@WithMockUser`. But if you need test only for logic you can disable `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` for tests

Answer (score 0):

1. Other response is right on the need to remove your `setUp()` method (`@Authowired MockMvc` is enough with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`)
2. **You should not use `@WithMockUser`** (which populates test security context with `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` instance, but either

- `@WithMockJwtAuth` from https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons
- `mockMvc.perform(get(...).with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt()...))` from spring-security-test

3. If using `@SpringBootTest`, like you do, security config should be active, but if using `@WebMvcTest`, you'll probably need to `@Import` or `@ComponentScan` it

You'll find complete usage sample [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/webmvc-jwtauthenticationtoken)

Sample unit test with the two flavors (annotation and MockMvc post processor to help you choose):

```java
@WebMvcTest(GreetingController.class)
@Import(SampleApi.WebSecurityConfig.class)
class GreetingControllerAnnotatedTest {

    @MockBean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc api;

    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth(authorities = "ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL", claims = @OpenIdClaims(sub = "Ch4mpy", preferredUsername = "Tonton Pirate"))
    void greetWithAnnotation() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/greet")).andExpect(content().string("Hello Ch4mpy! You are granted with [ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL]."));
    }

    @Test
    void greetWithPostProcessor() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/greet").with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt()
                .authorities(List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL"))).jwt(jwt -> {
                    jwt.subject("Ch4mpy");
                    jwt.claims(claims -> claims.put(StandardClaimNames.PREFERRED_USERNAME, "Tonton Pirate"));
                }))).andExpect(content().string("Hello Ch4mpy! You are granted with [ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL]."));
    }
```